# Two variants of a function with a simple if statement in the middle

Tags: c++, dry

This question is kind of a design one. Basically I often ten to end up with a function which performs high computation, but it has an if statement somewhere in the middle of it, which has a big impact on the performance of the whole program.

Consider this example:

```
void f(bool visualization)
{
    while(...)
    {
        // Many lines of computation
        if (visualization) 
        {
            // do the visualization of the algorithm
        }
        // More lines of computation
    }    
}
```

The problem in this example is, if the `bool visualization` is set to false, I guess the program will check it it's true each iteration of the loop.

The one solution is to just make two separate functions, with and without the visualization:

```
void f()
{
    while(...)
    {
        // Many lines of computation
        // More lines of computation
    }    
}

void f_with_visualization()
{
    while(...)
    {
        // Many lines of computation
        // do the visualization of the algorithm
        // More lines of computation
    }    
}
```

So now I don't have `if` checks. But it creates another problem: a mess in my code and it's a violation of DRY.

My question here is: Is there a way to do this better, without copying the code? Or maybe the C++ compiler optimizer would check which version of a function I want to execute (with bool = true or bool = false) and then create a dummy functions without this `if` check itself (like the ones I created myself)?

Comment: `but it has an if statement somewhere in the middle of it, which has a big impact on the performance of the whole program.` are you sure about that? Since the expression never changes during one run of the function, your branch predictor has a very high hitrate and the branch is essentially free.

Comment: Read up on [Branch Prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor). This is something that should already be taken care of for you. Have you actually profiled the program and found that this if-statement is in fact a problem?

Comment: You can templetize the function on the bool parameter, then the compiler will emit two different versions, potentially optimizing the false version better due to less code. You'll need to profile it though to be sure.

Comment: In addition to scohe001, as he wrote "Have you actually profiled the program", if you wonder how this is done, a common tool for C++ for profiling is gprof. And I totally agree with him - the right way to go is to first try out the program and only optimize if the speed is not satisfactory, then second you use a profiling tool to find out where the bottleneck lies. Improving something that needs no improvement is a waste of time.

Comment: Create functions for `// Many lines of computation` and `// More lines of computation`, and then you just repeat function calls (2 lines).

Answer (score 1):

You can template the function on the bool parameter and use `if constexpr`. Like this:

```
template<bool visualization>
void f_impl()
{
    while(...)
    {
        // Many lines of computation
        if constexpr (visualization) 
        {
            // do the visualization of the algorithm
        }
        // More lines of computation
    }    
}

void f(bool visualization)
{
    if (visualization)
        f_impl<true>();
    else
        f_impl<false>();
}
```